# How to stop C storing values that creep into operation?

Tags: c, initialization, printf, scanf

I write a simple program which multiplies two numbers.
When I multiply it by getting scanf input, it prints out random answers...

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a, b ,c = a * b;
    printf("Type two no.s to be multiplied, ensuring space between them");
    scanf("%d%d", &a, &b);
    printf("The required  output is = %d\n", c);
    return 0;

}
```

When I input 8 and 7 I get 4897 as my answer, well answer must be 56.

Comment: Why are you setting c to be equal to a multiplied by b before a and b have been initialised or set to their values?

Comment: `int a, b ,c = a * b;`???  What do you think that code puts into `c`?  And where in your code do you change that value?  Code operations in C are *sequential* - `c = a * b` does not cause `c` to be reevaluated when either `a` or `b` change later in the code.

Comment: It doesn't work for the very same reason as you expect `printf` to be executed before the user enters input through `scanf`. C programs are executed from the top to the bottom.

Comment: The computer follows the instruction from top to bottom except when you tell it not to

Answer (score 7):

C isn't Excel.  This:

```
c = a * b
```

Doesn't mean that `c` will always contains the value of `a * b`.  It means that you're setting `c` to whatever the value of `a * b` *currently* is at that point in the code.

You need to move this to *after* you read the values of `a` and `b`.

```
int a, b ,c;

printf("Type two no.s to be multiplied, ensuring space between them");
scanf("%d%d", &a, &b);

c = a * b;
printf("The required  output is = %d\n", c);
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that your order of operations is incorrect ... you must do the multiplication *after* the scanf:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a, b, c;

    printf("Type two numbers to be multiplied, ensuring space between them: ");
    scanf("%d%d", &a, &b);

    c = a * b;

    printf("The required output is = %d\n", c);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The initializer of the variable `c` does not make sense because there are used uninitialized variables `a` and `b`

```
int a, b ,c = a * b;
```

Using uninitialized variables invokes undefine behavior.

You need to calculate the value of the variable `c` after the variables `a` and `b` will get their values.

Also pay attention to that according to the C standard the function main without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

And as the multiplication in general can result in overflow it will be much better to declare the variable `c` as having the type `long long int`.

The program can look like

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    int a, b;
    long long int c;

    printf( "Type two no.s to be multiplied, ensuring space between them: " );

    if ( scanf( "%d%d", &a, &b ) == 2 )
    {
        c = ( long long int )a * b;
        printf( "The required output is = %lld\n", c );
    }
    else
    {
        puts( "Invalid input. Try again." );
    }

    return 0;
}
```